# Three.js - how to draw a discontinuous line using BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, line

I have the following situation: I need to draw a Line with holes (a discontinuous line). That means that my Line consists of several segments which are not combined visually but they belong together in some other context. These segments consists of more than just two points, so not the way like `THREE.LinePieces` works.

At this time, I am using a `BufferGeometry` to store my vertices. A colleague told me, that in WebGL it is possible to create two arrays additional to the vertices: one which contains the indices of the vertices and one which contains the order of how the vertices should be combined. 
Here an example of what I mean:

```
indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
vertices = [x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5]
order = [0,1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
```

With this I would get two lines: the first one from Point 0 over 1 to 2, then a hole, then a second line from 3 over 4 to 5.

So something like this:

```
.___.___.   .___.___.
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

I am not familiar with WebGL, so I'm trusting my colleague that it is possible to create such a construct. But is this also possible with Three.js? If yes, how do you do it?

---

EDIT:
I talked once more to my colleague and I got this code snippet

```
indexBufferData = [0,1,1,2,3,4,4,5];
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             indexBufferData.limit() * Buffers.SIZEOF_INT,
             indexBufferData, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

He said I only have to duplicate the indices and NOT the vertices (would also be possible but not recommended) to get line segments.

So I searched in the `WebGLRenderer` and saw on line 2380 that if there is an attribute `index` in my `BufferGeometry`, the necessary buffer will be created. But setting this attribute has no effect. When using `THREE.LinePieces` it is still connecting only two points.

Comment: But how do I define these gaps? The documentation of `THREE.LinePieces` says "first connected to the second, the third connected to the fourth, and so on and so forth". How do you say the line to connect e.g. four points to one segment and then do a gap? I don't want to add the vertices twice.

Comment: Sorry, you would have to add vertices twice. If you do not have many gaps, you could have separate line geometries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to draw a series of connected line segments, followed by a gap, and then another series of connected line segments, you use `THREE.LineSegments` for that.

For example, this is the pattern for a line with three segments, followed with a line with one segment:

```
v0, v1, v1, v2, v2, v3, v4, v5
```

Looks like this:

```
.___.___.___.   .___.
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

three.js r.91

Comment: Hm okay, so there is no possibility to do it like my colleague told me? What a shame. I hoped for a solution without adding the vertices twice :/ At this time I have seperate lines for each segment, but this isn't very handy. Ok so I must try to duplicate my vertices. I'm curious about my performance.

Comment: I edited my question. Perhaps it is now clear what I'm searching for. I couldn't find if the `index` is calculating anywhere in the Three.js code, maybe it is overwriting my proposition?!?

Answer (score 8):

A code example and a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/bd8trrLx/)** to play around with.

```
// .___.___.___.   .___.
// 0   1   2   3   4   5

// line material
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff
});

vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(20, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(30, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(40, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 0)
];

var positions = new Float32Array(vertices.length * 3);

for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {

    positions[i * 3] = vertices[i].x;
    positions[i * 3 + 1] = vertices[i].y;
    positions[i * 3 + 2] = vertices[i].z;

}

indices = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array(indices), 1));

var line = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```